# Convergence in Distribution, Probability, mean, quadratic mean and almost sure.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)$,  $n \ge 1$  be a sequence of independent real random variables on $\Omega$ such that:

$X_n \sim \mathrm{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right) $

For some $\alpha > 0 $. Consider the sequence $(Y_n)$,$n \ge 1$ of a real random variables on $\Omega$ given by:

$Y_n = \min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$

**QUESTION**: After characterizing $Y_n$, study the convergence in distribution, in probability, in mean, quadratic mean and almost sture convergence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ on varying of $\alpha \ge 0$.

I need to demostrate explicitly the convergence, considering the distribution funcition of $X_n$ we have:

$$  F_x(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}, & \text{if $0 < x < 1$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and for $Y_n$ we have:
$$
\begin{split}
Y_n &= \min\{X_1,\dots,X_n\} \\
&= P(X_1\le x_1)\cdots P(X_n\le x_n) \\
&= P(X\le x)\cdots P(X\le x) \\
&= P(X\le x)^n
\end{split}
$$
and considering the distribution function we have:
$$
  F_y(y) = F_x(z)^n =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
\left(1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)^n, & \text{if $0 < x < 1$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let's first consider the $X_n$ case:

According to the definition of weak-convergence, i will do the limit of the distribution function, so we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_x(x)  = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x \ge  0$}
\end{cases}
$$

At the end $X_n \to \operatorname{Dirac}(0)$.

Considering the convergence in probability, according to the definition, we have to demonstrate that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n - X| < \epsilon)  = 1$$

So at the end we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n - X| < \epsilon)  \\
=lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n | < \epsilon)  \\
=lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n = 0) \\
= lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{n^\alpha} = 1 $$

We have successfully demonstrate the convergence in probability of $X_n$

Now Considering the $Y_n$ case we hawe:

According to the definition of weak-convergence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_y(y)  = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha},  & \text{if $0 < x < 1$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now i'm stuck on this..

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Your '$Y_n = \min\{X_1,\dots,X_n\} 
= P(X_1\le x_1)\cdots P(X_n\le x_n) $' is incorrect. CDF of $Y_n$ is $P(Y_n\le y)=1-P(X_1>y,\ldots,X_n>y)=\cdots$